# Virtual function with static class?

Tags: c#, static-methods, virtual-functions

if I define under the same namespace 2 functions in 2 different classes as below

```
namespace Cache
{ 
    /// <summary>
    /// Cache manager interface
    /// </summary>
    public interface ICacheManager
    {
        T Get<T>(string key);
    }
}

namespace  Cache
{
    class CacheManager : ICacheManager
    {
        public virtual T Get<T>(string key)
        {
            return (T)Cache[key];
        }
    }
}

namespace Cache
{
    public static class CacheExtensions
    {
        public static T Get<T>(this ICacheManager cacheManager, string key, Func<T> acquire)
        {
            return Get(cacheManager, key, 60, acquire);
        }
    }
}
```

If i create an instance

```
ICacheManager _cacheManager;
```

and when I call the  `_cacheManager.Get(key,()=>myfunction())` method with parameters like that it will redirect to the `CacheExtensions` class rather than `CachManager` class although `ICacheManager` was inherited from it? Could you kindly explain how does it work overriding a function with shared? How is that getting related?

Comment: "What does this mean?" - Stack overflow.

Comment: Edited already. thanks

Comment: I still say - "stack overflow".

Comment: You effectively have two functions on your `ICacheManager` instance, `Get<T>(string)` and `Get<T>(string, Func<T>)`. When you call `_cacheManager.Get(key,()=>myfunction())` only the second one matches. There's no ambiguity here, what are you asking about?

Comment: This code is recursive - you never call the instance method, only the static one. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, extension method is not a function overriding. 
To be more accurate - overriding applicable for virtual(abstract) functions. In your case - it more close to overloading.

Basically, extensions is just a just a sugar, for not to have Action1(Action2(Action3(Action4(obj)))), but extensions will be translated to this.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx

If you need to call instance method from extension - use reference passed under 'this' keyword.